# match regex with state, but not city (or vice versa)

Tags: regex

I have a series of URLs in this format

```
/category/state/city
```

I'd like to match

```
/category/state
```

but not

```
/category/state/city
```

I've tried using a lookahead to eliminate situations where there are 3 forward slashes, but I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For the whole URL:

```
^http://(/[^/]+){2}$
```

For just the path:

```
^(/[^/]+){2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

`^\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*$` matches:

```
^             start of string
\/            exactly 1 /
[^\/]*        0 or more non-/ characters ("category")
\/            exactly 1 /
[^\/]*        0 or more non-/ characters ("state")
$             end of string
```

You can of course modify `[^\/]*` to more precisely limit what counts as a state or category (for instance `[^\/]+` doesn't allow the empty string, and `\w*` only allows word characters).